# Split html row into string array

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, toarray

I have data in an html file, in a table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>001</td><td>MC Hammer</td><td>Can't Touch This</td></tr>
    <tr><td>002</td><td>Tone Loc</td><td>Funky Cold Medina</td></tr>
    <tr><td>003</td><td>Funkdoobiest</td><td>Bow Wow Wow</td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I split a single row into an array or list?

```
string row = streamReader.ReadLine();

List<string> data = row.Split //... how do I do this bit?

string artist = data[1];
```

Comment: Did you just write a question about parsing HTML and tag it `regex`? That's going to get you in trouble (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I can remove the offending regex tag if it bothers anyone. Having said that, It's not like I'm trying to regex the entire html tag set. There are only 3 possible things it needs to match: `<tr><td>`, `</td><td>` or `</td></tr>`. I don't know much about regex, but I'm pretty sure it can cope with that requirement without the world ending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** never try to parse HTML from the wild with regular expressions. It will most likely come back to haunt you.

**Longer answer:** As long as you can absolutely, positively guarantee that the HTML that you are parsing fits the given structure, you can use string.Split() as Jenni suggested.

```
string html = "<tr><td>001</td><td>MC Hammer</td><td>Can't Touch This</td></tr>";

string[] values = html.Split(new string[] { "<tr>","</tr>","<td>","</td>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<string> list = new List<string>(values);
```

Listing the tags independently keeps this *slightly* more readable, and the `.RemoveEmptyEntries` will keep you from getting an empty string in your list between adjacent closing and opening tags.

If this HTML is coming from the wild, or from a tool that may change - in other words, if this is more than a one-off transaction - I **strongly** encourage you to use something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead. It's pretty easy to integrate, and there are lots of examples on the Intarwebs.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know string.Split could take an array, so that's enough to solve it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your HTML is well-formed you could use LINQ to XML:

```
string input = @"<table>
    <tr><td>001</td><td>MC Hammer</td><td>Can't Touch This</td></tr>
    <tr><td>002</td><td>Tone Loc</td><td>Funky Cold Medina</td></tr>
    <tr><td>003</td><td>Funkdoobiest</td><td>Bow Wow Wow</td></tr>
</table>";

var xml = XElement.Parse(input);

// query each row
foreach (var row in xml.Elements("tr"))
{
    foreach (var item in row.Elements("td"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

// if you really need a string array...
var query = xml.Elements("tr")
               .Select(row => row.Elements("td")
                                 .Select(item => item.Value)
                                 .ToArray());

foreach (var item in query)
{
    // foreach over item content
    // or access via item[0...n]
}
```

Comment: beautiful answer !

Answer (score 2):

When parsing HTML, I usually turn to the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Row.Split /<tr><td>|<\/td><td>|<\/td><\/tr>/
```

But it depends on how regular the HTML is. Is it programmatically generated, or does a human write it? You should only use a regular expression if you're sure it will always be generated the same way, otherwise you should use a proper HTML parser